# Criteria of finite Lebesgue measurability1

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I've been stuck at this problem for a while. I'm to show that the following two statements are equivalent.

$(i)$ $E$ is a *Lebesgue measurable set* with *finite measure*.

$(ii)$ For every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ a *bounded open set* $U$ such that $m^*(E \Delta U) \leq \epsilon$.

To show $(i) \implies (ii)$, I've used the *almost open* criteria of *Lebesgue measurability* to conclude that for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists$ a *bounded open set* $V$ with *finite measure*, such that $m^*(E \Delta V) \leq \epsilon$. But I'm having difficulty with the *boundedness* part. I guess an *open set* with *finite measure* doesn't necessarily has to be *bounded*.

To show $(ii) \implies (i)$, again we can use the *almost open* criteria of *Lebesgue measurability* to conclude that $E$ is a *Lebesgue measurable set*. But somehow I need to use the *boundedness* condition to imply that $E$ has a finite measure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(i) \implies (ii)$ Since $E$ is measurable $m(E) = m^*(E)$ so $\forall \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ there exists $O=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}I_i$ where $I_i$ are disjoint open intervals, such that $E\subset O$ and $m(E) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}>m(O)$. Since E has finite measure O has finite measure so $\lim_{n \to\infty} \sum_{i=n}^{\infty}m(I_i) = 0$. In particular there exists N such that $X=\bigcup_{i=N}^{\infty}I_i$, $ m(X) \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let S=O\X

$$E\Delta S = (E\setminus S) \cup (S \setminus E)) = (E\setminus(O\setminus X)) \cup ((O\setminus X)\setminus E)\subset X \cup (O\setminus E)  $$
So $m^*({E\Delta S}) \leq m^*({X}) + m^*(O\setminus E)\leq \frac{\epsilon}{2} +\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon  $ . Note that S is bounded as required (as a finite union of intervals). Note also that I freely switch between outer measure and measure for sets with are clearly measurable.

Comment: Please clarify the definition of $X$ (it is defined to be sum of measures). I don't see how $S$ necessarily contains $E$.

Comment: I meant X to be union of intervals, of course. Sorry for this typo. Edited it now. S does not necessarily contain E but O does (I defined it that way).

Comment: Alright. This is beautiful. :-)